# Replicate visual basic POST Request

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, httpwebrequest

I've inherited some pseudo code (Looks like VB with C terminator) that I need to implement in C# asp.net

```
Dim objHttp: Set objHttp = Server.CreateObject("Msxml2.ServerXMLHTTP");
objHttp.open "POST", "http:/somewebsite.php?data=" + Request.QueryString("xyz_custom"), False;
objHttp.setRequestHeader "Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
objHttp.Send Request.Form;
```

I'm a bit stuck on how to properly replicate `objHttp.Send Request.Form` as I normally send parameters

So far I have the code below, is this the correct way to do it?

```
string qString = Request.QueryString["xyz_custom"];
string url = "http:/somewebsite.php?data=" + qString;
HttpWebRequest objHttp = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
objHttp.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
objHttp.Method = "POST";
objHttp.KeepAlive = false;
objHttp.Credentials = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;

//Is the following the same as objHttp.Send Request.Form;

byte[] _byteVersion = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(Request.Form.ToString());
Stream requestStream = objHttp.GetRequestStream();
requestStream.Write(_byteVersion, 0, _byteVersion.Length);
requestStream.Close();
```

Comment: BTW, that's VBScript.

Comment: A good read for you is (http://blogs.msdn.com/b/robmen/archive/2004/05/20/136530.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

To perform the post action in c# it is simply:

```
<form method="post" runat="server" action="URL to page you want this form submitted to">
    //data controls to be posted
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" name="buttonSubmit" />
</form>
```

Anytime the button is clicked, it submits the form to the form action.

***UPDATE***

When no controls are present, use something like:

```
Response.Redirect("WebForm2.aspx?id=123&data=123");
```

And then retrieve the variable(s), by:

```
var variable = Request.QueryString["id"];
```

***UPDATE 2***

When unknown variables need to be passed, it is:

```
var test = "data";
var test2 = "data";
Response.Redirect("WebForm2.aspx?data=" + test + "&data2=" + test2);
```

Retrieve the variables the same way as described above.

If no variables need to be passed, simply using:

```
Response.Redirect("WebForm2.aspx");
```

***UPDATE 3***

Better understanding of how variables work:

Lets take a look at youtube for a second.  When you click a link to a video, it sends you to a url like:

> http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5fKM6UyFecE

If you look at the end of their URL, you will see:

```
watch?v=5fKM6UyFecE
```

What this tells us, is that the actual page you are being redirected to is `watch` and the variable `v` is set to `5fKM6UyFecE`.  What happens is that the watch page takes the variable v's value and then shows the user the results from that variable.  In this case, it is a video page stored within the database.

Therefore to do an external link, you would make it something like the following:

```
Response.Redirect("http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5fKM6UyFecE")
```

Hope all this helps.

Comment: I need it in code behind as there is no button or controls on the form.

Comment: Here, let me even give you the way to place unknown variables in the redirect.

Comment: Sorry about all the edits, just trying to ensure that it is all formatted the same and easier to understand.

Comment: I not sure if I can do that as I'm not redirecting to a page on my site. It's posting the query string details to an external site.

Comment: It still works, but you have to ensure the external uses the exact strings that you are setting.  Take youtube for example.  When you link to a specific video, look at the url, it actually has the variable that is used by the site to know which video someone needs to view.

Comment: Just added more to my answer to explain how this all works and how linking to externals works.

Comment: Thanks, I'll give it a try and let you know how I get on

Comment: Good luck.  Just updated to show how external links would look.